# Create TopicAssignment in apex

Tags: feeditem, topics, collaborationgroup

I am attempting to automate some chatter stuff.  What I want to do is use apex and create a new chatter feeditem, attach it to a group, and then assign a topic to it.  I am doing this for a community but can't get it to work in the community or in Salesforce as a system administrator.  Here is the code:

```
Topic topicObj = [SELECT Description,ManagedTopicType,Name,NetworkId,TalkingAbout FROM Topic WHERE id = '0TO1K000001Fi4BWAS'];
        CollaborationGroup cg = new CollaborationGroup();
        cg.CanHaveGuests = false;
        cg.CollaborationType = 'unlisted';
        cg.Name = 'My topic Test Group';
        cg.NetworkId = topicObj.NetworkId;
        cg.OwnerId = userinfo.getuserid();
        insert cg;
        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        post.ParentId = cg.Id;
        post.NetworkScope = topicObj.NetworkId;
        post.Body = 'this is a test';
        post.IsRichText = true;
        post.Status = 'Published';
        post.Type = 'TextPost';
        post.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
        post.Title = 'subject';
        insert post;
        TopicAssignment ta = new TopicAssignment();
        ta.EntityId = post.id;
        ta.NetworkId = topicObj.NetworkId;
        ta.TopicId = topicObj.id;
        insert ta;
```

the error I get every time is

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, Failed to assign topic to 0D556000008c7kQ. Please ensure you have permissions to assign topics for this record.: [EntityId]

Comment: Does the profile have `Assign Topics` System Permission set to true? I tried with the code above with minor changes on record ids, etc. and it works fine. The topic is assigned and I could see it on the record in the community.

Comment: @JayantDas yes the user has the Assign Topics permission.